# JSPs, static content, SpringBoot jars and IntelliJ

Tags: spring-boot, jsp, intellij-idea

So I'm developing in IntelliJ a spring boot app.  Using Gradle, I'm creating the sprint boot jar file.

I'm having problems figuring out where to put the jsps and static content such as .js files in such a way that running the jar AND running from within IntelliJ works!

It seems that in order to get SpringBoot to find jsps in a jar file I need to put the jsps inside a src/main/resources/META-INF/resources directory.  For example, META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/index.jsp.  I'm pretty sure the WEB-INF is now meaningless.

However, if I try to run this spring boot app from within IntelliJ, it cannot find the jsp.  404, blah blah blah.  I actually have to put the jsps in the war-style webapp directory in src/main.  However that directory is totally ignored during the spring boot jar build.

So.. how do developers set up their development environments that is both IntelliJ and, say, gradle bootRun friendly?

Comment: There is a guide at https://htr3n.github.io/2018/12/jsp-spring-boot/ which should work both in IntelliJ IDEA and in the command line via the `war` file which can be executed as a `jar` (via `java -jar`).

Comment: CrazyCoder I love you.  If wouldn't mind making an Answer entry here I'll be able to mark you as the genius you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [guide here](https://htr3n.github.io/2018/12/jsp-spring-boot/) which should work both in IntelliJ IDEA and in the command line via the `war` file which can be executed as a jar (via `java -jar`).

Answer (score 0):

As per spring boot there are Limitations when it comes to jsp's.

To overcome these limitations we need to have the configuration made in the application to render jsp by placing the jsp's under src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/jsp folder.

Sample Code: [Click Here](https://github.com/girishkkumar/spring-boot-2-jsp-jar-example/)

References:

https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-with-jsps-in-executable-jars-1

https://github.com/hengyunabc/spring-boot-fat-jar-jsp-sample

Comment: Oh.. I could get the spring boot to render the jsps, but then IntelliJ couldn't locate them when running the application.  If I moved them to where IntelliJ expected them, then the executable failed to find them.  However, CrazyCoder's pointer to a solution worked well for me.